# If $\lambda $ is an eigenvalue of A such that $|\lambda| = \rho(A)$, then deg$\lambda \leq $ deg $\rho(A)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

Let $K$ denote a proper cone in $\Bbb R^n, n>1$, $\pi(K)$ denote the set of all matrices which leaves the cone invariant. Let $\rho(A)$ denote the spectral radius of the matrix $A$.

**Def**: Let $\lambda $ be an eigenvalue of $A$. The degree of $\lambda $, deg$\lambda $, is the size of the 
largest diagonal block in the Jordan canonical form of A, which contains $\lambda $.

> Then I want to show that if $\lambda $  is an eigenvalue of A such that $|\lambda| = \rho(A)$, then deg$\lambda \leq $ deg $\rho(A)$.

In other words degree of $\lambda $ can also be thought as the multiplicity of $\lambda $ in the minimal polynomial of $A$.

Comment: What is $\mathrm{deg}\, \rho(A)$?

Comment: I have trouble understanding your definition of $\deg$. Suppose $A=\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}0&1&0\\ 0&0&0\\ \hline0&0&0\end{array}\right]$. Then the size of the largest diagonal block in $A$ is $1$, which is the size of the $0I_1$ at the bottom right corner, but the multiplicity of $0$ in the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $2$.